# Why do we need to decompose $f$ into positive and negative parts to prove these basic measure theoretic properties?

Tags: measure-theory

Below is an excerpt:

[image]

The part I've highlighted in red is referring to the proof of the second part. I don't understand why it is necessary to split up $h, f, g$ into these six parts. Why can't you directly say: $$h = f + g \implies \int h d\mu = \int f d\mu + \int g d\mu$$ I have no idea why this idea of positive and negative parts is introduced suddenly before proving these things and I am curious why because it is hindering my understanding of these proofs.

Comment: Try proving these things without splitting into positive and negative parts. See what happens.

Comment: Look at the definition of $\int$ that is used here.

Comment: Oh so it's because $f$ is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$ whereas the integral is only defined on $[0,\infty]$ - correct?

Answer (score 1):

In measure theory it is very common to prove things only for positive functions. Then decompose any given function $f$ into a linear combination of positive functions $ f = f^+ - f^- $.

There are many results that are  stated $\textbf{only}$ for positive functions, such as Lebesgue's monotone convergence Theorem. (Check its hypothesis) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem

So analyze a function by using what you know of positive functions.